# Using request.object as a parentObject of another class in afterSave

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am trying to use CloudCode afterSave to to create childObjects of the object that triggered the afterSave.

Its my understanding that request.object is the object that was just saved.  I have been able to access all of the fields of the request.object but for my life can't figure how to set it to the parent field of the object that I am creating in this function.

An example of my code:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Reservation", function(request) {

  var aDate = request.object.get("arrivalDate");
  var dDate = request.object.get("departureDate");

  aDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  dDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);

  aDate = Date.UTC(aDate.getFullYear(), aDate.getMonth(), aDate.getDate());
  dDate = Date.UTC(dDate.getFullYear(), dDate.getMonth(), dDate.getDate());

  var dateDiff = Math.abs(aDate-dDate);
  dateDiff = dateDiff/1000/60/60/24;
  console.log(aDate);
  console.log(dDate);
  console.log(dateDiff);
  console.log(request.object);

  var datesArray = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < dateDiff; ++i) {

      var ResDay = Parse.Object.extend("ResDay");
      var resDay = new ResDay();

      var newDate = new Date(aDate);

      newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + i);

      resDay.set("aResDate", newDate);
      resDay.set("parentReservation", request.object);

      datesArray[datesArray.length] = resDay;
  }
        console.log(datesArray);
});
```

Now I realize that I haven't called anything to save the new ResDay objects yet, thats because I can't get past setting the request.object as their parent yet.

The log that I am getting is: Uncaught Tried to save an object with a pointer to a new, unsaved object.

I have tried numerous iteration's trying to set it.  In iOS it works like this but I can't figure out the javascript:

```
resDay["parentReservation"] = reservation //While reservation is a PFObject
```

Ive spent two days googling and SO'ing and Im fried. Calling out for some assistance.  If you need any other info in order to give me some guidance please ask.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a bug, as the reservation object should be saved at this point.

Try the following:

```
// not sure what your class name is, replace as needed
var reservation = new Parse.Object("Reservation");
reservation.id = request.object.id;
// reservation is now a bare-bones pointer we can use
resDay.set("parentReservation", reservation);
```

Also try logging the id just to be sure:

```
console.log(request.object.id);
```

Comment: Tim, your suggestion moved me through that portion of the issue so I am accepting your answer.  What I have drilled this down to is trying to log objects to the console like this: console.log(resDay); resDay being a Parse object that I am trying to create. Am curious to know what is wrong in my format for logging that entire object?

Comment: Try `console.log(resDay.toJSON());` instead.